# MySQL how to rank marks/ position of subject marks of one student

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have table called MARKS, I have these columns

```
STUDENT_ID, CLASSFORM_NAME, ACADEMIC_YEAR, TERM,  SUBJECT_NAME, TOTAL_MARKS
```

so I want to select the rank of the total marks based on the subject_name, classform_name, term and academic_year for one particular student

This is the query I used but not working

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT total_marks, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS scorePosition
      FROM marks m, (SELECT @curRank := 0) q
      WHERE classform_name=? AND term=? AND academic_year=? AND subject_name=?
     ) t
WHERE student_id =?
ORDER BY total_marks DESC
```

Help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the data *before* you assign the ranking.  To be safe, use a subquery:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS scorePosition
      FROM (SELECT m.*
            FROM marks m
            WHERE classform_name = ? AND term = ? AND academic_year = ? AND subject_name = ?
            ORDER BY total_marks DESC
           ) m CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @curRank := 0) q
     ) m
WHERE m.student_id = ?;
```

Comment: It still didn't work. Same error. Trying to get property 'erro' of non-object. It means the query couldn't even run right. I'm using mySQL as DBMS

Comment: It says unknown column 'student_id' in where clause

Comment: I've Modified it by adding the student_id  But the output is not what I want, it's it showing the position as 1 even though there are other lager marks than this particular student's subject mark own................

Comment: Seems to be working now.... Will load it with more data and test it further... Thanks Very much. You really saved me a lot of time

Comment: Please how do I make it considere ties, because it doesn't consider the ties.

Comment: @Kwakuamoh . . . If you have a question about ties, ask *another* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.  This question suggests that you don't care about ties.

Comment: Ok. But I've been restricted for asking question till after two days. But I really need help on this. I tried but not giving me the desired results with ties